# Make it faster to check if a certain regex is present in the text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem. I want to check whether a certain regex occurs in a text (This regex will become more complex later.). Unfortunately, my code snippet runs, but it takes a long time. How could I rewrite the code to make it faster and more efficient?

If the element is present in the text, the code number of the respective element should be found and written into a new column. If it is not present, `999` should be written

Dataframe

```py
   customerId                text element  code
0           1  Something with Cat     cat     0
1           3  That is a huge dog     dog     1
2           3         Hello agian   mouse     2
```

Code snippet

```py
import pandas as pd
import copy
import re
d = {
    "customerId": [1, 3, 3],
    "text": ["Something with Cat", "That is a huge dog", "Hello agian"],
     "element": ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['code'] = df['element'].astype('category').cat.codes
print(df)

def f(x):
    match = 999
    for element in df['element'].unique():
        check = bool(re.search(element, x['text'], re.IGNORECASE))
        if(check):
            #print(forwarder)
            match = df['code'].loc[df['element']== element].iloc[0]
            break
    x['test'] = match
    return x
    #print(match)
df['test'] = None
df = df.apply(lambda x: f(x), axis = 1)
```

Intended output

```py
   customerId                text element  code  test
0           1  Something with Cat     cat     0     0
1           3  That is a huge dog     dog     1     1
2           3         Hello agian   mouse     2   999
```

Comment: SO all you want is, if element occurs in text test=code, if not text=999, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: I have written an answer, let me know if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas `apply` to iterate through all the `text` and check if `element` exist in `text`. Here is one of the solution using `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

d = {
    "customerId": [1, 3, 3],
    "text": ["Something with Cat", "That is a huge dog", "Hello agian"],
     "element": ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['code'] = df['element'].astype('category').cat.codes
df['test'] = np.where(df.apply(lambda x: x.element.lower() in x.text.lower(), axis=1), df['code'], 999)
```

Output :

```
df
   customerId                text element  code  test
0           1  Something with Cat     cat     0     0
1           3  That is a huge dog     dog     1     1
2           3         Hello agian   mouse     2   999
```

You can also do the same thing in `lamda` function using `df.apply`

```
df['test'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.code if x.element.lower() in x.text.lower() else 999, axis=1)
```

This gives us the same thing

```
df
   customerId                text element  code  test
0           1  Something with Cat     cat     0     0
1           3  That is a huge dog     dog     1     1
2           3         Hello agian   mouse     2   999
```

Comment: This produces a different answer from OP code if we change text in d to: `"text": ["Something with Dog", "That is a huge cat", "Hello agian"],`

Comment: @DarrylG in that case we expect test to be `0, 999, 999` and that is what my code is giving

Comment: But, OP code produces: 1, 0, 999 in that case.

Comment: OP wants to copy the column `code` if the condition is met and if not replace by 999

Comment: OP claim was their code was too slow (so assume correct but just needed better performance).  But, It could be that OP code is also incorrect.

Comment: `If the element is present in the text, the code number of the respective element should be found and written into a new column. If it is not present, 999 should be written`

Comment: I agree the description does not match the code.  In this case, let's assume their code is incorrect while the description is correct.  Thus, your code is good because it matches the description.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) then use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to fill with `df['code']` and `999`.

```
import numpy as np

mask = df['text'].str.contains('|'.join(df['element']), case=False)
df['test'] = np.where(mask, df['code'], 999)
print(df)
```

But if you want to get the output for `"text": ["Something with Dog", "That is a huge Cat", "Hello agian"]` as `[1,0,999]`. You can create `dict` with `element` and `code`. If `element` with regex search exist use `code` value in `Dict` or replace `999`.

```
import re
dct = dict(zip(df['element'].str.lower(), df['code']))
pattern = re.compile("|".join(dct.keys()), re.IGNORECASE)
df['test'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: dct[pattern.search(x).group(0).lower()] if pattern.search(x) else 999)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   customerId                text element  code  test
0           1  Something with Cat     cat     0     0
1           3  That is a huge Dog     dog     1     1
2           3         Hello agian   mouse     2   999
```

Comment: This produces a different result than OP when we modify d by swapping the position of Cat and Dog in text i.e. : `"text": ["Something with Dog", "That is a huge Cat", "Hello agian"]`

Comment: @DarrylG, see update...

Comment: From comments with Himanshu Poddar answer your original code could have been correct (i.e. OP code may be incorrect).  But, I'll upvote this answer since it agrees with OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the already written functions of pandas to make it a lot faster.

```py
# ...
for element in df['element'].unique():
    matching = df[df['text'].str.match(element) == True]
    # ...
```

The `matching` variable contains all the rows that are matching with the given regex code (`element`).

Also, you can read more about pandas and regex in this excellent site: https://kanoki.org/2019/11/12/how-to-use-regex-in-pandas/.